# Exclude AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument Class from coverage report in coverlet

Tags: c#, unit-testing, code-coverage, xunit, coverlet

I have this class **AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Users__AddOrUpdateUser** appearring in the code coverage result for each view in the Views folder,

Exemple:
**AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Users__AddOrUpdateUser**
**AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Users__GetUser**
etc...

*Assembly*: **Solution.Web**
*Class*: **AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument**

I want to exclude this folder using the **.runsettings** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RunSettings>
    <DataCollectionRunSettings>
        <DataCollectors>
            <DataCollector friendlyName="XPlat code coverage">
                <Configuration>
                    <!-- Globbing filter -->
                    <ExcludeByFile>**/Solution.Web/Views/*.cshtml</ExcludeByFile>
                    <IncludeTestAssembly>false</IncludeTestAssembly>
                    <DeterministicReport>false</DeterministicReport>
                </Configuration>
            </DataCollector>
        </DataCollectors>
    </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

this is the result i want: this image is from dotCover it allows creating a filter easily
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to exclude all the AspNetCoreGenerateDocument files excluding the pre-compiled views (cshtml) from sources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <DataCollectionRunSettings>
        <DataCollectors>
            <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
                <Configuration>
                    <CodeCoverage>
                        
                        <ModulePaths>
                            <Include>
                                <ModulePath>.*whatever.dll</ModulePath>
                                <ModulePath>.*whatever2.dll</ModulePath>
                            </Include>
                        </ModulePaths>

                        <Sources>
                            <Exclude>
                                <Source>.*cshtml.*</Source> 
                            </Exclude>
                        </Sources>
                        
                        <!-- We recommend you do not change the following values: -->

                        <!-- Set this to True to collect coverage information for functions marked with the "SecuritySafeCritical" attribute. Instead of writing directly into a memory location from such functions, code coverage inserts a probe that redirects to another function, which in turns writes into memory. -->
                        <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
                        <!-- When set to True, collects coverage information from child processes that are launched with low-level ACLs, for example, UWP apps. -->
                        <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
                        <!-- When set to True, collects coverage information from child processes that are launched by test or production code. -->
                        <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
                        <!-- When set to True, restarts the IIS process and collects coverage information from it. -->
                        <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>
                        <!-- When set to True, static native instrumentation will be enabled. -->
                        <EnableStaticNativeInstrumentation>True</EnableStaticNativeInstrumentation>
                        <!-- When set to True, dynamic native instrumentation will be enabled. -->
                        <EnableDynamicNativeInstrumentation>True</EnableDynamicNativeInstrumentation>
                        <!-- When set to True, instrumented binaries on disk are removed and original files are restored. -->
                        <EnableStaticNativeInstrumentationRestore>True</EnableStaticNativeInstrumentationRestore>

                    </CodeCoverage>
                </Configuration>
            </DataCollector>
        </DataCollectors>
    </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

The rest of the .runsettings document is the same as per documentation: [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis?view=vs-2022)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).